# why is my swift app icon missing in archive

Tags: ios, swift

When trying to archive my app, for some reason the app icon is missing and instead this image appears:
[image]

What's odd is that when I run it on a simulator or even connect my own iPhone, the icon shows up, the only time it's missing is when I archive it and I'm not sure how to fix this.

Comment: Did you downlaod it from App Store?

Comment: No I'm trying to upload it to Apple Connect so I can upload it to the app store, it's not available for download yet